Regex that allow alphanumerics, spaces, dots, hyphens, but not an empty string
I have this REGEX in Java that alllow simple short sentences with alphanumerics, dots, hyphens and white spaces:
Pattern MAX_LENGTH_30_NO_SPECIAL_CHAR_ = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9\\s\\-.]{1,30}");
String sentence = "This is a good idea.";
boolean m = MAX_LENGTH_30_NO_SPECIAL_CHAR_ .matcher(sentence).matches(); // true, OK

String empty = "    ";  // should not match, but matches


How could change that pattern to not match empty sentences?

Negate all spaces in input by using (?!\\s+$)[A-Za-z0-9\\s.-]{1,30} as regex

@anubhava looks like it works!

You've used a character class so it's quite at liberty to choose anything from it to match on, including the whitespace that's in the class

note that given pattern(s) will also match text with line feed ("x\ny") carriage return ("x\ry") form feed("x\fy")  vertical tab (x\u000By" ) and similar (use \\h instead of \\s to avoid that, if needed)
